# Show image in CollectionView from gallery

Tags: swift3, uicollectionview, uiimagepickercontroller

I want to show images selected from gallery into an ImageView which is in CollectionView. How do I do this??
Showing selectedImage in normal ImageView is working fine.

Below is my code:

```
var selectedImage = UIImage ()
@IBAction func selectPics(_ sender: Any)
{
    if self.picsCollectionView.isHidden == true
    {
        self.picsCollectionView.isHidden = false
        self.imageView.isHidden = true
    }

    self.picker.allowsEditing = true
    self.picker.sourceType = .photoLibrary
    present(self.picker, animated: true, completion: nil)
}

func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info:[String: Any])
{
    if let image = info[UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage] as? UIImage
    {
        selectedImage = image
    }
    else if let image = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage
    {
        selectedImage = image
    }
    else
    {
        print("Something went wrong")
    }

    self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int
{
    return 1
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell
{
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath as IndexPath) as! UploadCollectionViewCell

    cell.cellImgView.image = selectedImage

    return cell
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found an answer. Needed to add just one line.

Below is the solution:

```
func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info:[String: Any])
{
    if let image = info[UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage] as? UIImage
    {
        selectedImage = image
        self.picsCollectionView.reloadData()
    }

    else if let image = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage
    {
        selectedImage = image
        self.picsCollectionView.reloadData()
    }

    else
    {
        print("Something went wrong")
    }

    self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```